# Select values in one column where that value do not appear in other column 5 times

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, union, exists

Suppose I have a SQL table `members` with two columns: `username` and `sponsor`:

```
username | sponsor
------------------
bill     | bob
username1| bill 
username2| username2
username3| bill   
username4| bill  
username5| bill   
username6| bill  
username7| bill  
collin   | username6
austin   | usename3
```

I would like to write a query that returns all the username where in those usernames do not appear 5 times in column sponsor. How do I write this SQL query?

Desired Output:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
username5
username6
username7
collin
austin
```

Comment: Something like SELECT * FROM members WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM members GROUP BY sponsor WHERE COUNT(*)<>5).

Comment: Did you receive an error or did it produce incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT m.username
  FROM members m,
    (SELECT sponsor, COUNT(sponsor)
      FROM members
      GROUP BY sponsor
      HAVING COUNT(sponsor) < 5) c
  WHERE m.username = c.sponsor
```

I assume from your sample output you want members who have sponsored **fewer than** 5 other members.

Comment: The one you DID was displaying only

username2
username6
username3

Answer (score 0):

This query answered the problem.

```
SELECT m.username FROM members m, (SELECT sponsor, COUNT(sponsor) FROM members GROUP BY sponsor HAVING COUNT(sponsor) >= 5) c WHERE m.username != c.sponsor
```

Thanks Darwin!